# Which bikes come with SRAM Automatix

Tags: shifter, sram

I rented a bike with SRAM Automatix once and it was a pleasure to ride. I'm not sure what the brand was and I couldn't find any information online as to which bikes come with this hub.

I guess I could buy a wheel set and put it on any bike but I'm wondering if somebody knows a few popular models that ship with it. Thanks!

Update: I found IKEA Sladda that is available pretty much anywhere in the world and comes with Automatix along with other nice features

Comment: There's one bike at work with this , and its not just the hub.  There's a control box on the handlebars, and that has a battery inside.  You'll be best buying a whole bike.

Comment: @Criggie - you're thinking of something else. Automatix gear shifting mechanism is completely contained in the hub. The only cable you may need to run with Automatix to the back is possibly a brake cable. The coaster variety won't need one, but the freewheel variety should have a rim brake on the rear wheel and you'll need a cable for that. The other two choices are roller brakes and disc brakes which will also need cables run to the back.

Comment: That said - I searched Ebay and there's a heap of 2 speed automatix hubs by themselves.   That could be a basis for a wheel build, which is not cheap but is better than a whole bike.

Comment: Sorry, but we don't do product recommendations and a list of products would be a never-ending project that would be perpetually out of date.

Comment: The problem with buying just a hub is that you need to be able to build the wheel yourself, or know someone who can (to sufficient quality). Most people don't have either option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those who aren't familiar, a SRAM Automatix hub is a 2-sped internal gear hub which shifts automatically, with the shift mechanism and everything contained in the hub. The mechanism is mechanical, and there aren't any batteries or anything involved. So, no cables to the back of the bike needed except for a brake cable if you have a freewheel Automatix (rim brake), disc brake Automatix or roller brake automatix. The coaster brake variant will not need a brake cable, obviously. There are in some sense similar products from Sturmy Archer (Sturmy Archer Kickback, which you backpedal a bit to shift), but the Automatix is the leader of the pack since shifts automatically without any user intervention.

While Automatix hubs are  pretty reliable and work well, they aren't very popular in the grand scheme of bicycles. And whats available is highly market dependent.

You're primarily going to find automatix on things marketed as city bikes or something similar. Major manufacturers like Specialized have had them in the [past](https://www.missionbicycle.com/blog/hands-free-shifting), but you might end up having to go with a more boutique manufacturer (e.g. [Mission Cycles](https://www.missionbicycle.com/blog/hands-free-shifting)). Your bike shop should be able to help you.

The swapping in of an automatix wheel is straightforward but not necessarily trivial; you have to sort out your rear brake situation (coaster, disc or roller in the hub, or have the hub freewheel and use a rim brake), have the right hub spacing for your frame and an appropriate rim size. I'd say its not significantly easier than getting a bike with automatix in the first place.